# Any group of order $85$ is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

> Any group of order $85$ is cyclic.

My attempt:

Let $|G|=85=5\times17$

Let $H_1$ be the sylow-$5$ and $H_2$ be sylow-$17$ subgroup of $G.$

Then $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$

So $|H_1\times H_2|=85$

and hence $G\simeq H_1\times H_2$

Since $H_1\times H_2$ is cyclic so is $G.$

---

I'm not sure about my proof. Please tell me whether it's correct! Apart from voting please leave comment.

Comment: Trivial intersection does not guarantee that $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $H_1\times H_2$. For that to happen you have to show that an arbitrary element of $H_1$ commutes with an arbitrary element of $H_2$. The usual tool giving us this is (as in Taro's answer) to show that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are both normal. A consequence of this is that a commutator $h_1h_2h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}\in H_1\cap H_2$, and we are done. To deduce normality you need either Sylow's theorem or other tricks described in the answers by Marshal Kurosh and Scaramouche.

Comment: My favorite way here would be to use Sylow theorem's only to tell that there exist single subgroups of respective orders $5$ and $17$. Here all non-trivial subgroups are Sylow! Therefore there are $85-5-17+1=64$ elements of $G$ that don't belong to any non-trivial subgroup. Therefore any one of them has to generate $G$, and $G$ is thus cyclic.

Answer (score 10):

*One more step is needed*. Recall that one of a definition of direct product $G = H \times K$ is $H, K \trianglelefteq G$, $G = \langle H, K \rangle$, and $H \cap K = 1$. Hence, you have to show that $H_1, H_2 \trianglelefteq G$. (This can be easily shown by Sylow's theorem.)

Otherwise your proof fails. Such an example is $S_3$. Though Sylow subgroups $C_2$, $C_3$ of $S_3$ have trivial intersection $C_2 \cap C_3 = 1$ and $\lvert C_3C_2 \rvert = 6$ (which implies $S_3 = C_3C_2$), $S_3$ is not the direct product of the two. (Observe that  $C_2 \not \trianglelefteq S_3$ in this case.)

Answer (score 3):

**"Proof by Lagrange-Cauchy-Frobenius-Burnside Theorems"**

(*) If $H,K$ are subgroups of a finite group, then $|HK|=\frac{|H|.|K|}{|H\cap K|}$.

1) Suppose $G$ is abelian. Then by **Cauchy theorem for finite abelian groups**, $G$ has elements $x,y$ of order $17$ and $5$, respectively. As $x,y$ comute and have relatively prome order, the order of $xy$ must be $85$, and $G$ is cyclic. (*Cauchy theorem for finite abelian groups can be very easily proved by* * ).

2) Suppose $G$ is non-abelian. Then $Z(G)<G$, hence center has order either $1,5$ or $17$ by **Lagrange theorem**. The later two are impossible, otherwise $G/Z(G)$ will be cyclic, so $Z(G)=1$. The **Frobenius class equation** for $G$ becomes

$|G|=|Z(G)|+|C_G(x_1)|+|C_G(x_2)| + \cdots |C_G(x_r)|$ (where $C_G(a)=$ conjugacy class of $a$ in $G$). Let $|C_G(x_i)|=n_i$. 
Hence, $85=1+n_1+n_2+\cdots n_r$.

2.1) For $a\in G$, $a\neq 1$, by **Lagranges theorem**, $a$ has order $5$, $17$ or $85$; if it is $85$, then $G$ is cyclic, so consider first two possibilities. If $a$ has order $5$, then the centralizer of $a$ has order $\geq 5$, and it divides $|G|$, it should be $5$ since $Z(G)=1$. Therefore, $|C_G(a)|=85/5=17$. Similarly, if $a$ has order $17$, then $|C_G(a)|=5$. Therefore, in the class equation, $n_i$ is one of $5$ and $17$. In particular, $n_i\geq 5$, and from class equation, we deduce that, $r\leq 16$. Hence $G$ has at most $17$ conjugacy classes.

2.2) By a **theorem of Burnside** (probably 1902), in a group of odd order, the number of conjugacy classes is congruent to $|G|$ mod $16$. Hence, $(r+1)\equiv 85$ mod $16$, and $r+1\leq 17$ (by 2.1). The only solution of this equation is $r=4$. Hence $85=1+n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4$, with $n_i\in \{5,17\}$. This is impossible, since RHS is at most $69$.

Hence $G$ is abelian, and by (1), it is cyclic.

---

**Comment** The purpose of this solution is to show how *very basic* theorems (shown with bold case letters) can be beautifully used to understand structure of finite groups. Especially, I have not used general Cauchy theorem, but only for finite abelian groups, which can be quickly proved by *. But, the theorem of Burnside has non-trivial proof. It is included in very less books of group theory, and this is an opportunity to show it to the people, who never met it.

Comment: +1, but I think that using Sylow's theorem is more elementary than using Burnside.

Comment: sorry! very simple proof will be just by Sylow theorems. But, here, as mentioned in my comments, I wanted to use some basic theorems just as "tools". Its purpose it to use wherever possible to theorems we know to investigate unknown things.

Comment: even without Sylow theorems and just by Lagranges theorem, it can be proved. In the problem, Sylow theorem implies existence of subgroups of order $5$ and $17$ and gives exact number of such subgroups. But, by Lagranges theorem and some simple counting, we can deduce this easily.

Comment: Understood! It is refreshing to see tools other than Sylow at work.

Comment: @Jyrki: exactly!!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a shot at a solution without using the Sylow theorems -- please tell me if anything I say is false.

We begin by considering $|Z(G)|$. If this is 85 we are done. We claim that it is neither $5$ nor $17$. Indeed, if it is $5$, we have that the action of $G$ on itself by conjugation has kernel containing $Z(G)$; hence taking the quotient, we find that $G/Z(G) \simeq \mathbb Z / ( 17 \mathbb Z)$ acts on $G$ by conjugation. Hence non-trivial conjugacy classes must be size $17$, which is incompatible with the class equation since $5 + 17 n \neq 85$. Similarly if $|Z(G)| = 17$ then $17 + 5n \neq 85$ which shows that this case is impossible as well.

Hence the only case left is $|Z(G)|  =1$, which we will also show is impossible. Since the size of a conjugacy class must divide the order of $G$, the class equation tells us
$1 + 5n + 17m = 85$,
which has the unique solution $n=10, m=2$.

Now, by Cauchy's theorem there exists a cyclic subgroup $H \leq G$ of order $17$, i.e. index $5$. We look at the action of $G$ on the cosets $G/H$ which gives a homomorphism $G \rightarrow S_5$. We find that the kernel of this action is contained in $H$ and has index at most $5$ and hence is $H$, i.e. $H$ is a normal subgroup.

However, a normal subgroup must contain the identity and be a union of conjugacy classes, and since $1 + 5n' + 17 m' \neq 17$ for any choice of $0\leq n' \leq n, 0 \leq m' \leq m$, this is impossible as well.

So $G = Z(G)$ is Abelian of order 15, which means it must be cyclic.

Comment: But the way one uses to prove that a group of order $15$ is cyclic (very last paragraph) can be used to prove precisely the claim, as $5\nmid 17-1$.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that underlying point here is that $5$ does not divide $17-1=16$. Using Sylow's theorems, if a group has order $pq$ for $p<q$ then the Sylow $q$-subgroup $H_q$ is normal. Combined what what you said, this means we have a semi-direct product.

Note that $H_p$ and $H_q$ are cyclic. Now, it is "well-known" (It is! Honest!) that if $C_q$ is the cyclic group of order $q$ then $\operatorname{Aut}(C_q)\cong C_{q-1}$. Therefore, the action of $H_p$ on $H_q$ is non-trivial if and only if $p$ divides $q-1$. Here, $5$ does not divide $17-1=16$ and so the action is trivial. Therefore, we have a direct product.

If you were to keep plugging away at the (non-direct) semi-direct product case, you will find that there is precisely one isomorphism class (for fixed $p$, $q$), basically because $p$ is prime. Therefore, we can conclude with the following result,

**Lemma:** Suppose $G$ has order $pq$, $p<q$. If $p$ does not divide $q-1$ then $G$ is cyclic. If $p$ divides $q-1$ then there are precisely two isomorphism classes of order $pq$,  that is, either $G\cong C_{pq}$ or $G$ is the semidirect product $G\cong\langle a, b; a^p, b^q, a^{-1}ba=b^p\rangle$.

For example, $S_3$ has order $6=2\cdot 3$, and $2$ divides $3-1=2$. This is why $S_3$ is not simply $C_2\times C_3\cong C_6$.