# Existence of natural number solution for given equation.

Tags: number-theory

p and q are odd primes such that p>q. Does the equation (k-p)q= k-1 have any natural number k as the solution? I have proved that no natural number up to p+1 satisfies the equation. I am unable to come to a conclusion regarding natural numbers beyond p+1. Kindly help me solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: $k=19$, $p=13$ $q=3$

Comment: I came across this equation trying to solve a group theory problem.Can you help me with it?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469871/existence-of-group-of-order-p-in-group-of-order-pq-pq?s=14|2.3091

Comment: Looking at the argument in that link, I don't see any elementary way to complete it.  Maybe I am missing something.  You could write to that author and ask.  Cauchy's Theorem really seems like the way to go with that exercise.  I can probably invent an argument specific to groups of order $pq$ but I doubt it will be significantly easier than the general case.

Comment: Thanks. I would have asked but I lack points to comment on other people's questions.

Comment: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67129/groups-of-order-pq-without-using-sylow-theorems) is another problem which claims to address groups of order $pq$ separately.  If you look through the answers to that I think you'll find leads on how to do it without the general theory.  I have not gone through them carefully myself, however, so can't attest to their accuracy or completeness.

Answer (score 1):

At least one solution exists
$$k=7,q=3,p=5$$
$$(7-5)3=7-1$$
$$6=6$$

Comment: Thanks. I actually came to this equation trying to solve an algebra problem. Can you help me with it. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469871/existence-of-group-of-order-p-in-group-of-order-pq-pq?s=14|2.3091